# Photo Importer is in German, not English

Tags: windows, windows-8

My Photo Importer that came with my Lenova desktop is in German.  How can I change it to English?

Comment: We need a lot more information here... What's the name of the application? Can you link to their website? What have you tried so far?

Comment: have you tried to change the location (inside the control panel-language settings) to USA?

Comment: It came with my Lenova desktop and is called Photo Importer.  Yes, the location inside the control panel-language setting is set to USA

Answer (score 1):

You can change the default by going through the control panel-hardware and sound-autoplay-change default settings for media-memory card

Change it to import photos and videos (photos) and you will escape the foreign language although you could continue to guess your way through the photo importer which is fairly easy. Haven't figured out how to change it but it appears it is Lenovo specific.

Answer (score -1):

**UPDATE:** *This answer is incorrect, and will be voluntarily submitted for deletion. See comments below.*

I recommend you contact the program developer. His contact information can be found here: http://zenangst.com/page/contact. It appears that internationalization functionality was a [recently added feature](http://zenangst.com/app/photoimporter#releasenotes), so there may be a bug, but there is likely an easy way to switch it.

(Oh, and by the way, welcome to superuser!)

Comment: I may have the answer:  The Photo Importer is a Windows 8 app. and the photo importer I emailed said his program is for MACS.

Comment: Oops. In that case my answer is entirely wrong. Sorry for the "wild goose chase". Turns out a [lot of other people have complained about the same problem](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22photo+importer%22+lenova&rls=com.microsoft:en-us&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&startIndex=&startPage=1#bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=76ff4ca0492ff220&q=%22photo+importer%22+lenova+%7C+lenovo+language&rls=com.microsoft:en-us), so it's not just you. I'm sorry I couldn't help.

Comment: you might try the suggestions in [this post](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-pictures/photo-importer-is-set-to-differnet-language/c4d70ef7-f552-440f-82ad-d53c7b387f34?tab=question&status=AllReplies)